# Java can't find symbol

Tags: java, select, applet

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*; 

public class Stuff extends Applet implements ActionListener
{
    Button okButton; 
    public void init() 
   {    
       setLayout(new FlowLayout());
       okButton = new Button(""); 
       add(okButton); 

       okButton.addActionListener(this); 
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   { 
       if (okButton.getState()) 
       g.setColor(Color.black); 
       g.drawRect(20, 20, 200, 200);
   }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
   { 
        if (evt.getSource() == okButton)  
            repaint();
   }
}
```

Comment: Post the exact error message !

Comment: voting for close, no details.

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to actually put your `init()` code in the constructor so you are not required to call a second method before you class acts the way you intend it to? You should also fix the indentation of the if block in `paint()` so it is clear that only `setColor()` is conditional.

Comment: Is this a puzzle for us?

Comment: @unholysampler Actually, no - generally, you want your constructor to do as little as you can get away with.

Comment: Thanks for the help I understand what I did wrong.

P.s. Your great siten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think button don't has a `state`. It isn't like a `Checkbox` to get the state as if it is marked or not. So, `okButton.getState()` is the error.

An explanation of what you are trying to achieve would help every one to help you. Don't just post the code, leaving to us to decipher what you are trying to achieve .

Answer (score 0):

`java.awt.Button` has no method `getState`. Did you mean to add an `ActionListener` to it so you can know when it has been clicked?

Answer (score 0):

i just run your program i see the button just add cast of okButton....

Comment: and just remove getState becouse awt can't understand... and add if (okButton.getName() != null)